# Can only center last label in Row Layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm just starting out with the HTML client and, clearly, I'm doing something wrong. But I'm not even sure what a lot of things are called so I don't know what to search for to help myself. But I'm thinking that the problem lies in my lack of understanding of jQuery as this should be really simple.

I have the following layout:

[image: Screen Designer]

With the following code behind:

```
myapp.Splash.lblCopyright_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
    $("label").addClass("custom-center-label");
};
```

And the following in `user-customization.css`:

```
/* Custom Classes */
.custom-center-label {
    text-align: center;
}
```

My screen ends up looking like this:

[image: Rendered page]

I can see in the DOM Explorer that the class is getting applied correctly and the Computed properties call for text-align to be center:

[image: DOM Explorer]

So I have two questions. First and foremost, why can I only get the last label in my Row Layout to be centered when all labels have the same class? And second, why, with the code that I have in the single Local Property's function, do all label's get the class added?

Comment: 1) At a guess i'd suggest you might have to set all of the controls to 'Stretch to Container' including the parent controls (Row/Column Layouts)

Comment: 2) Missing element context: try:  $("label", element).addClass("custom-center-label");

Comment: @Kris Comment 1) worked perfectly and gave me the look I wanted. However, `$("label", element).addClass("custom-center-label");` did not work and the class was not applied to the label at all. Neither did `$(element).find("label").addClass("custom-center-label");` as was suggested to me when I cross posted to [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b6a00dcd-c3b1-468c-8733-b43b3d3d0139/can-only-center-last-label-in-row-layout?forum=lightswitch). Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: @Kris joshbooker in the MSDN thread gave me a good idea for solving the second problem. Change the label to a paragraph and use `$(element).find("p").text("©2012-2016, MyCompany, Inc.");` to populate the text and `$(element).find("p").addClass("custom-center-label");` to assign the class in the `_postRender` method or use `contentItem.screen.lblCopyright = "©2012-2016, MyCompany, Inc.";` in the screen's created method. Apparently labels are a bit weird in the HTML client. But since your first comment is what solved the bigger problem, feel free to add it as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Lightswitch drives me nuts, glad you got it sorted mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set all of the controls to 'Stretch to Container' including the parent controls (Row/Column Layouts)
2. You are missing the 'element' context in your jQuery selector.